# Can someone diagnose this JACK error message?

Tags: audio, alsa, jack

OK. I start JACK without starting the JACK server. I get:

```
23:09:22.730 Patchbay deactivated.
23:09:22.765 Statistics reset.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
23:09:23.059 ALSA connection graph change.
23:09:23.250 ALSA connection change.
```

Then I press the 'play' button.

I get:

```
23:10:07.865 Startup script...
23:10:07.866 artsshell -q terminate
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
sh: artsshell: not found
23:10:08.268 Startup script terminated with exit status=32512.
23:10:08.268 JACK is starting...
23:10:08.269 /usr/bin/jackd -dalsa -dhw:0 -r44100 -p1024 -n2
23:10:08.275 JACK was started with PID=1764.
Cannot create thread 1 Operation not permitted
Cannot create thread 1 Operation not permitted
jackdmp 1.9.6
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2010 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Cannot lock down memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Using ALSA driver HDA-Intel running on card 0 - HDA Intel at 0xdfebc000 irq 42
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 1024 frames (23.2 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/10)(1: Operation not permitted)
AcquireSelfRealTime error
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
alsa_driver_xrun_recovery
JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, skip cycle
23:10:15.341 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Server communication error.
```

If I press nothing, the above read error message repeats infinitely.

I installed JACK from repositories and this is what I got.

Comment: What OS are you doing this on? Where did you get JACK (OS package, compiled it yourself, …)? What exact commands did you run?

Comment: Debian Lenny, from repos. I ran it from the GUI and simply pressed the play button. The same works on the repo version installed on Debian Squeeze several days ago.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu 10.10.  It worked a few weeks ago; not sure what's changes since then

Comment: @redmoskito: Why are you running such an outdated distro? If you are going to go that long before getting the newest release, you should be running the LTS.  You might 'technically' be considered 'supported', but by the skin of your teeth.  The regular releases are not meant for 'long-term' stability, even though they might seem stable enough.  The requirements for inclusion, are drastically different between a 6-month and LTS.

Comment: @TechZilla Please note the date of my post.

Comment: @TechZilla I no longer have access to the machine that prompted this question, so i can't test any suggestions. sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your missing permissions, does your distro set up an `audio` group?  Is your user a member of that group?

Which version of JACK do you have installed?  JACK2 is preferred, and I believe Debian provides decent configurations.  To install JACK2, run this command...

```
sudo apt-get install jackd2
```

If you already have jack2 installed, do a reconfigure like this...

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p high jackd2
```

If you still are experiencing problems comment, I'll follow up.